# REST content delivery

Tags: content-delivery, 2013, rest

I hear 2013 will include some sort of REST API for delivery of content?  I want to completely decouple my application and call REST services to retrieve the content blocks to compose a page.

Ideally I'd like to do that with some sort of URI base as well as request a block of content via TCM ID and get some JSON data back to then render in some way.  Is this going to be possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're 2 years late to the party then. The Tridion Content Delivery Service (REST, ODATA) has been available since Tridion 2011 GA, and there are already quite a few sites being built exactly as you want to.

Given Tridion's generic Content Model on the delivery tier, still expect to see "Content" as one of your data elements. As long as your templates in Tridion output JSON, then you will get JSON on the delivery tier too.

The beauty of it using ODATA is that:

1. The API is actually [pretty well documented](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/uri-conventions/)
2. There's a HUGE amount of [client libraries](http://www.odata.org/libraries) out there.
3. It will soon be an [OASIS standard](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=odata).

Almost forgot. For a full JSON response, make sure to add $format=json to all your requests.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a DD4T-esque delivery model for this? I would essentially like to create generic data blocks of arbitrary complexity which are simply the result of composition of components into a data structure which is transformed to JSON at the service endpoint - all templating and data visualisation activity should be the responsibility of the application domain (which could be an iOS app, a web site page, a syndication service, etc)

Comment: I've heard of a company that actually modified DD4T to consume content from the ODATA Web Service instead of using the CD API. Don't know of other people, but since it's ODATA, there's a lot of stuff out there - and it doesn't have to be from Tridion.

Comment: If you join the DD4T Discussion group here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion the code for the DD4T OData provider has been posted there. It's not currently in the core framework.